What happens when a servlet that is used to handle exceptions throws itself an exception?
I have a Java Servlet web application configured to handle any exception that bubbles up to the container via a dedicated servlet: "/errorHandler".
What happens if this Servlet, while handling an exception, throws a new exception that bubbles up to the container?
Will the container handle this exception and invoke again the /errorHandler servlet or avoid that because it could introduce an infinite circular loop of invocations?
When testing on Jetty, it did not. It's unclear to me, however, if this behavior is specific to my servlet container or required of all implementations.
I have read the Servlet specifications (https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-4-final-eval-spec/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf) but I haven't found an answer there.
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">
    <error-page> 
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type> 
        <location>/errorHandler</location> 
    </error-page>
</web-app>


You should be more specific to your problem and include [mre].
